# The dimension of the space of automorphic forms with multiplier system

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete subgroup of $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\vartheta$ a multiplier system of weight $k$ for $\Gamma$, by which we mean a function $\vartheta:\Gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $\mid \vartheta(\gamma)\mid=1 $ and $\vartheta(\gamma_1 \gamma_2)=w(\gamma_1,\gamma_2)\vartheta(\gamma_1)\vartheta(\gamma_2)$ for all $\gamma, \gamma_1,\gamma_2$ in $\Gamma$, where $w(,)$ is the factor system of weight $k$ as defined in Iwaniec's book "Topics in classical automorphic forms". I have two questions:

1) First, in page 44, Iwaniec says that the space $M_{k}(\Gamma,\vartheta)$ of automorphic forms for $\Gamma$ with multiplier $\vartheta$ of weight $k$ has finite dimension, but in general one does not know its exact value. The value of the dimension is well known when the multiplier is trivial, but it is unknown in the general case. Since 1997, the year when Iwaniec's book was printed, is there now any general formula to compute the dimension in the general case?

2) Second, take the particular case where the multiplier system $\vartheta$ is the one of the theta functions, is there any dimension formula for the space $M_{k}(\Gamma,\vartheta)$ in this particular case?

I need references, thank you.